# String contains all the elements of a list

Tags: python, regex, list

I am shifting to Python, and am still relatively new to the pythonic approach. I want to write a function that takes a string and a list and returns true if all the elements in the list occur in the string.

---

This seemed fairly simple. However, I am facing some difficulties with it. The code goes something like this:

---

```
def myfun(str,list):
   for a in list:
      if not a in str:
         return False
      return True
```

---

```
Example : myfun('tomato',['t','o','m','a']) should return true
          myfun('potato',['t','o','m','a']) should return false
          myfun('tomato',['t','o','m']) should return true
```

---

Also, I was hoping if someone could suggest a possible regex approach here. I am trying out my hands on them too.

Comment: Then you would probably be good by selecting a better problem that needs Regex. This doesn't. In fact you are doing it fine.

Comment: If you want to get better and try out regex-related tasks, try http://www.regex101.com/quiz/

Comment: `myfun = lambda a, b: all(i in a for i in b)`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
>>> all(x in 'tomato' for x in ['t','o','m','a'])
True
>>> all(x in 'potato' for x in ['t','o','m','a'])
False
```

Comment: What if  want to traverse through the characters of the string and see if all of them are from the list or not ?

Comment: Then use a list comprehension.

Comment: Can you just give in a demo as to how I could use that ? In between I am surely going to check it out !!

Answer (score 3):

```
def myfun(str,list):
   for a in list:
      if not a in str:
         return False
   return True
```

return true must be outside the for loop, not just after the if statement, otherwise it will return true just after the first letter has been checked. this solves your code's problem :)

Comment: Thank you.. I got it now. In between, these indentations are a bit confusing to say the least for someone new to the language !!

Answer (score 3):

For each letter you go through the list. So if the list is of length `n` and you have `m` letters, then complexity is `O(n*m)`. And you may achieve `O(m)` if you preprocess the word.

```
def myfun(word,L):
    word_letters = set(word) #This makes the lookup `O(1)` instead of `O(n)`
    return all(letter in word_letters for letter in L)
```

Also, it's not a good practice to name variables as `str` and `list` as if you will need later to create `list` or use `str`, they will be shaded by your variables.

Some relevant information:

- [`all`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#all) function
- [`set` complexity](http://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity#set)

Answer (score 2):

If you're not worried about repeat characters, then:

```
def myfunc(string, seq):
    return set(seq).issubset(string)
```

And, untested, if you do care about repeated characters, then maybe (untested):

```
from collections import Counter
def myfunc(string, seq):
    c1 = Counter(string)
    c2 = Counter(seq)
    return not (c2 - c1)
```

Comment: string is a name of Python module, so that naming variable _string_ is not such a good idea

Answer (score 0):

For fun, I thought I'd do it with iterators and map:

```
from operator import contains
from itertools import imap, repeat

def myfun(str, list):
    return all(imap(contains, repeat(str), list))
```

Then I realised that this essentially does the same thing as the accepted answer, but probably with more method calls.

```
def myfun(str, list):
    return all(letter in str for letter in list)
```