# Matching set of keywords to a string variable parsed from json

Tags: json, python-2.7

So I have a array of keywords such as

```
keyword = ['Bob','hello','boot']
```

I parsed json and grabbed string value named title and input into name.

Title contain strings such as "Bob hey, hello boot"

I am trying to make it so that program would return only true if Title/name contains all the words from keyword array list.

Currently, I have this code

```
keyword = ['Bob','hello','boot']
name=str(item[u'title'].encode('ascii','ignore')) #grab Title and input into name
found_a_string = True
for word in keyword:
    if not word in name.lower():
         found_a_string = False
    if found_a_string:
         ID=str(item[u'id'])
         print name, ID, 'found' #would output full title and then assoicated ID from json.
```

But code return true as long as one of the words from keyword matche.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12999930/string-contains-all-the-elements-of-a-list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use all:

```
keyword = ['Bob','hello','boot']
name = "Bob hey, hello boot"
if all(x in name for x in keyword):
    ID=str(item[u'id'])
    print name, ID, 'found'
```