# Check if a string contains the list elements

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to check if a string contains the elements in a list?

```
str1 = "45892190"
lis = [89,90]
```

Comment: All the elements? Or just one? What about overlap?

Comment: @Willem All the elements in the list and no overlap

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please show your work. We're not here to do your work for you.

Comment: string = "45892190"
    lis = [89,90,77,8]
    for i in lis:
        if str(i) in string:
            lis.remove(i)
            print(lis)

    print(lis)

Comment: @Soviut didn't work so far

Comment: @SouvikRay please edit your answer to include that code, don't put it in a comment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [String contains all the elements of a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12999930/string-contains-all-the-elements-of-a-list)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If no overlap is allowed, this problem becomes much harder than it looks at first.
As far as I can tell, no other answer is correct (see test cases at the end).

Recursion is needed because if a substring appears more than once, using one occurence instead of the other could prevent other substrings to be found.

This answer uses two functions. The first one finds every occurence of a substring in a string and returns an iterator of strings where the substring has been replaced by a character which shouldn't appear in any substring.

The second function recursively checks if there's any way to find all the numbers in the string:

```
def find_each_and_replace_by(string, substring, separator='x'):
    """
    list(find_each_and_replace_by('8989', '89', 'x'))
    # ['x89', '89x']
    list(find_each_and_replace_by('9999', '99', 'x'))
    # ['x99', '9x9', '99x']
    list(find_each_and_replace_by('9999', '89', 'x'))
    # []
    """
    index = 0
    while True:
        index = string.find(substring, index)
        if index == -1:
            return
        yield string[:index] + separator + string[index + len(substring):]
        index += 1


def contains_all_without_overlap(string, numbers):
    """
    contains_all_without_overlap("45892190", [89, 90])
    # True
    contains_all_without_overlap("45892190", [89, 90, 4521])
    # False
    """
    if len(numbers) == 0:
        return True
    substrings = [str(number) for number in numbers]
    substring = substrings.pop()
    return any(contains_all_without_overlap(shorter_string, substrings)
               for shorter_string in find_each_and_replace_by(string, substring, 'x'))
```

Here are the test cases:

```
tests = [
    ("45892190", [89, 90], True),
    ("8990189290", [89, 90, 8990], True),
    ("123451234", [1234, 2345], True),
    ("123451234", [2345, 1234], True),
    ("123451234", [1234, 2346], False),
    ("123451234", [2346, 1234], False),
    ("45892190", [89, 90, 4521], False),
    ("890", [89, 90], False),
    ("8989", [89, 90], False),
    ("8989", [12, 34], False)
]

for string, numbers, should in tests:
    result = contains_all_without_overlap(string, numbers)
    if result == should:
        print("Correct answer for %-12r and %-14r (%s)" % (string, numbers, result))
    else:
        print("ERROR : %r and %r should return %r, not %r" %
              (string, numbers, should, result))
```

And the corresponding output:

```
Correct answer for '45892190'   and [89, 90]       (True)
Correct answer for '8990189290' and [89, 90, 8990] (True)
Correct answer for '123451234'  and [1234, 2345]   (True)
Correct answer for '123451234'  and [2345, 1234]   (True)
Correct answer for '123451234'  and [1234, 2346]   (False)
Correct answer for '123451234'  and [2346, 1234]   (False)
Correct answer for '45892190'   and [89, 90, 4521] (False)
Correct answer for '890'        and [89, 90]       (False)
Correct answer for '8989'       and [89, 90]       (False)
Correct answer for '8989'       and [12, 34]       (False)
```

Answer (score 6):

```
str1 = "45892190"
lis = [89,90]

for i in lis:
    if str(i) in str1:
        print("The value " + str(i) + " is in the list")
```

> OUTPUT:
>
> The value 89 is in the list
>
> The value 90 is in the list

If you want to check if all the values in lis are in str1, the code of cricket_007

```
all(str(l) in str1 for l in lis)
out: True
```

is what you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

If you want non-overlapping matches I'd do it like this:

- create a copy of the initial string (as we'll modify it)
- go through each element of the list and if we find the element in our string, we replace it with `x`
- at the same time, if we find the number in our string, we increment a counter
- at the end, if the variable equals the length of the list, it means that all of its elements are there

```
str1 = "45890190"
lis1 = [89, 90]

copy, i = str1, 0
for el in lis1:
    if str(el) in copy:
        copy = copy.replace(str(el), 'x')
        i = i + 1

if i == len(lis1):
    print(True)
```

More, we don't really need a counter if we add an extra condition which will return `False` when an element isn't found in the string. That is, we get to the following, final solution:

```
def all_matches(_list, _string):
    str_copy = _string
    for el in _list:
        if str(el) not in str_copy:
            return False
        str_copy = str_copy.replace(str(el), 'x')
    return True
```

Which you can test by writing:

> ```
> str1 = "4589190"
> lis1 = [89, 90]
>
> print(all_matches(lis1, str1))
>
> > True
> ```

This might not be the best solution for what you're looking, but I guess it serves the purpose.

Comment: fails for `all_matches([89, 90, 8990], "8990189290")`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) function

```
In [1]: str1 = "45892190"
   ...: lis = [89,90]
   ...: all(str(l) in str1 for l in lis)
   ...:
Out[1]: True
```

Comment: It looks like OP doesn't want any overlap.

Answer (score 0):

```
def contains(s, elems):
    for elem in elems:
        index = s.find(elem)
        if index == -1:
            return False
        s = s[:index] + s[index + len(elem) + 1:]
    return True
```

Usage:

```
>>> str1 = "45892190"
>>> lis = [89,90]
>>> contains(str1, (str(x) for x in lis))
True
>>> contains("890", (str(x) for x in lis))
False
```

Comment: Sadly, this doesn't work at all. `+1` is wrong. Also, it returns True for `"45892190"` and `[89,90,4521]`. PS: I didn't downvote

Comment: Improving this answer to work is actually trivial: instead of removing found numbers, replace them with a "placeholder" character (for example a space). Besides, the list should be first sorted in descending order, so that the longest numbers are matched first to avoid a problem illustrated by `contains("2302", [2, 23])`. Oh, and I am assuming the numbers in list are only positive integers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the regular expression to search.

```
import re
str1 = "45892190"
lis = [89,90]
for i in lis:
  x = re.search(str(i), str1)
  print(x)
```

Comment: Wow this works brilliant!Didn't think regex would be so handy!

Comment: @SouvikRay No it doesn't, please avoid accepting answers straight away without really looking into them. Try changing `str1` to `'890'` (instead of `'45892190'`) and [it still seems to work just fine](https://pastebin.com/ViFeRxJt). This answer doesn't take into account your "*and no overlap*" requirement, which you said in the comments.

Comment: If this answer really does work for you, and you don't actually care about overlap unlike you said in the comments (which makes this a duplicate question...), then I'd highly recommend using cricket_007 or Giovanni Gianni's answer instead, as they don't need to rely on regex.

Comment: I do agree that this code does not consider overlapping.

Comment: @SouvikRay This is objectively the worst answer. It doesn't check anything, it doesn't return anything, it doesn't consider overlapping, it's not Python-ish and it uses regexp even though it's not needed. As mentioned by Markus, if you don't care about overlapping, there are better, easier answers.

Comment: Guys! My mistake..I forgot to take into account overlapping.Yes the accepted answer doesn't consider overlapping which was one of my prime requirements.

Comment: @EricDuminil Your answer looks perfect so far and accomplishes the objective as far as I have tested.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to implement this correctly using regular expressions. Generate all unique permutations of the input, for each permutation connect the terms with ".*" then connect all of the permutations with "|". For example, [89, 90, 8990] gets turned into 89.*8990.*90| 89.*90.*8990| 8990.*89.*90| 8990.*90.*89| 90.*89.*8990| 90.*8990.*89 , where I added a space after each "|" for clarity."

The following passes Eric Duminil's test suite.

```
import itertools
import re

def create_numbers_regex(numbers):
    # Convert each into a string, and double-check that it's an integer
    numbers = ["%d" % number for number in numbers]

    # Convert to unique regular expression terms
    regex_terms = set(".*".join(permutation)
                            for permutation in itertools.permutations(numbers))
    # Create the regular expression. (Sorted so the order is invariant.)
    regex = "|".join(sorted(regex_terms))
    return regex

def contains_all_without_overlap(string, numbers):
    regex = create_numbers_regex(numbers)
    pat = re.compile(regex)
    m = pat.search(string)
    if m is None:
        return False
    return True
```

However, and this is a big however, the regular expression size, in the worst case, grows as the factorial of the number of numbers. Even with only 8 unique numbers, that's 40320 regex terms. It takes Python several seconds just to compile that regex.

The only time where this solution might be useful is if you have a handful of numbers and you wanted to search a lot of strings. In that case, you might also look into re2, which I believe could handle that regex without backtracking.